# How can I see the tables from a specific tablespace in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, console, sqlplus

I am trying to get the list of tables that I created and sent to a specific tablespace,
Could you please tell me which script or command should i write to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DBA_TABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/ALL_TABLES.html#GUID-6823CD28-0681-468E-950B-966C6F71325D).

If you are not familiar with the cited document, you should bookmark it at the TOC, the read through the TOC to get an idea of what's there.  Whenever I have a question similar to yours, the first thing I do is open the cited document, the start looking for data dictionary views that look promising.  In this case I double checked, not only to give you the link but to refresh my memory on if it would be DBA_TABLES or DBA_SEGMENTS.

Answer (score 0):

For tables created by the schema you are loged in:
Select table_name from user_tables where tablespace_name='TEST'
If you log in with sys, use dba_tables table instead